# Create a toolbar above textarea

Tags: html, css

I want to create a toolbar above textarea

like this with tool HTML and Preview

When HTML is clicked it will change name from HTML to Preview
When Preview is clicked back again it will toggle to HTML

[image]

```html
<style>
.container {
    width:500px;
    position: fixed;
}

.right-element {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="right-element">
        Preview
    </div>
  <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:75%;resize: none; " ><h3>At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. They offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.</h3></textarea>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some simple `border` and `text-align` action will give you the desired result:

```js
$(".right-element").click(function(){$(this).toggle(),$(this).siblings().toggle(),togglePreview()});let showPreview=!1;const w3Preview=$("#w3review-preview");function togglePreview(){showPreview?(w3Preview.hide(),$(w3review).show()):(w3Preview.html(w3review.value),w3Preview.show(),$(w3review).hide()),showPreview=!showPreview}
```

```css
.container{
  border: 5px solid #e6e7e6;
  font-family: system-ui;
}

.toolbar{
 border-bottom: 5px solid #e6e7e6;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: right;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.right-element{
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#html{
  display: none;
}

#w3review-preview{
  display: none;
}

.editor {
  padding: 10px;
}

textarea{
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <span class="right-element" id="preview">
      Preview
    </span>
    <span class="right-element" id="html">
      HTML
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="editor">
  <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:75%;resize: none; "><h3>At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. They offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.</h3></textarea>
  <div id="w3review-preview" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:75%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```